# When rendering ejs file, it does not show properly

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to render ejs file from nodejs express.
But it shows html codes with thes character � everywhere.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
res.render('index', { title: 'The index page!' })
});
```

And index.ejs is

```
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
welcome <%= title %>;
</body>
</html>
```

What did do I do wrong?

Comment: It seems that you have an ecoding problem, could you post the html also in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to be started

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
res.render('index', { title: 'The index page!' })
});
app.listen(3000);
```